# Upsampling categorical variable in time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data

I apologize if this is redundant, but I have tried to look for solutions, and have not found anything that appears to be the answer to my question. So, I have time series data for a bunch of variables. Some variables (continuous) were recorded at 1000hz, and the other variables (categorical) is at 500hz. I want to align them in R, such that the categorical variables have the same number of rows as the continuous variables. In other words, I would like to merge the two dataframes and fill in the gaps automatically for the categorical variables, so that my data, which looks like this:

| t_emg | CF_01 | CF_02 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.01796875 | 0.01234375 |
| 0.001 | 0.001875 | 0.05125 |
| 0.002 | 0.00828125 | -0.04140625 |
| 0.003 | -0.0125 | -0.005625 |
| 0.004 | -0.00765625 | 0.00078125 |
| 0.005 | -0.01 | 0.02234375 |
| 0.006 | 0.01515625 | -0.01296875 |
| 0.007 | -0.01375 | -0.070625 |
| 0.008 | 0.0096875 | 0.1534375 |
| 0.009 | -0.05203125 | 0.02984375 |
| 0.01 | 0.1234375 | 0.00765625 |
| 0.011 | -0.0596875 | 0.005625 |
| 0.012 | -0.09296875 | -0.001875 |
| 0.013 | -0.0834375 | -0.1128125 |
| 0.014 | -0.009375 | 0.0090625 |
| 0.015 | -0.00609375 | 0.02 |
| 0.016 | 0.00890625 | 0.0209375 |
| 0.017 | 0.02671875 | 0.00375 |
| 0.018 | -0.001875 | -0.0003125 |
| 0.019 | -0.00171875 | 0.00171875 |

and this:

| t_kinematics | Phase | stride_stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | swing | A |
| 0.002 | swing | A |
| 0.004 | swing | A |
| 0.006 | swing | A |
| 0.008 | swing | A |
| 0.01 | swing | A |
| 0.012 | swing | A |
| 0.014 | stance | A |
| 0.016 | stance | A |
| 0.018 | stance | A |

will end up looking like this:

| t_emg | CF_01 | CF_02 | t_kinematics | Phase | stride_stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.01796875 | 0.01234375 | 0 | swing | A |
| 0.001 | 0.001875 | 0.05125 | 0.001 | swing | A |
| 0.002 | 0.00828125 | -0.04140625 | 0.002 | swing | A |
| 0.003 | -0.0125 | -0.005625 | 0.003 | swing | A |
| 0.004 | -0.00765625 | 0.00078125 | 0.004 | swing | A |
| 0.005 | -0.01 | 0.02234375 | 0.005 | swing | A |
| 0.006 | 0.01515625 | -0.01296875 | 0.006 | swing | A |
| 0.007 | -0.01375 | -0.070625 | 0.007 | swing | A |
| 0.008 | 0.0096875 | 0.1534375 | 0.008 | swing | A |
| 0.009 | -0.05203125 | 0.02984375 | 0.009 | swing | A |
| 0.01 | 0.1234375 | 0.00765625 | 0.01 | swing | A |
| 0.011 | -0.0596875 | 0.005625 | 0.011 | swing | A |
| 0.012 | -0.09296875 | -0.001875 | 0.012 | swing | A |
| 0.013 | -0.0834375 | -0.1128125 | 0.013 | swing | A |
| 0.014 | -0.009375 | 0.0090625 | 0.014 | stance | A |
| 0.015 | -0.00609375 | 0.02 | 0.015 | stance | A |
| 0.016 | 0.00890625 | 0.0209375 | 0.016 | stance | A |
| 0.017 | 0.02671875 | 0.00375 | 0.017 | stance | A |
| 0.018 | -0.001875 | -0.0003125 | 0.018 | stance | A |
| 0.019 | -0.00171875 | 0.00171875 | 0.019 | stance | A |

Additionally, there are many NAs in the categorical data, and I would like those to be retained. All the information that I can find is more geared towards imbalanced data or imputation of missing values. It is also not really prediction, as I am really just interested in filling in the temporal gaps for the categorical variables.

Comment: is your data really one disjoint wrongly-combined frame like that, or is it two frames with three columns each?

Comment: It is actually two separate dataframes that I would like to merge; I just put them together in my question so it is easier to interpret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your single-frame, we really have two 3-column frames.

```r
quux1 <- structure(list(t_emg = c(0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.016, 0.017, 0.018, 0.019), CF_01 = c(-0.01796875, 0.001875, 0.00828125, -0.0125, -0.00765625, -0.01, 0.01515625, -0.01375, 0.0096875, -0.05203125, 0.1234375, -0.0596875, -0.09296875, -0.0834375, -0.009375, -0.00609375, 0.00890625, 0.02671875, -0.001875, -0.00171875), CF_02 = c(0.01234375, 0.05125, -0.04140625, -0.005625, 0.00078125, 0.02234375, -0.01296875, -0.070625,  0.1534375, 0.02984375, 0.00765625, 0.005625, -0.001875, -0.1128125, 0.0090625, 0.02, 0.0209375, 0.00375, -0.0003125, 0.00171875)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
quux2 <- structure(list(t_kinematics = c(0, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006, 0.008, 0.01, 0.012, 0.014, 0.016, 0.018), Phase = c("swing", "swing", "swing", "swing", "swing", "swing", "swing", "stance", "stance", "stance"), stride_stop = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(11:20, names = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "omit"))
```

Using this, we'll use `findInterval` to map the other columns to the time interval.

```r
intvl <- findInterval(quux1$t_emg, quux2$t_kinematics)
out <- cbind(quux1, lapply(quux2[,-1], `[`, intvl))
out
#    t_emg       CF_01       CF_02  Phase stride_stop
# 1  0.000 -0.01796875  0.01234375  swing           A
# 2  0.001  0.00187500  0.05125000  swing           A
# 3  0.002  0.00828125 -0.04140625  swing           A
# 4  0.003 -0.01250000 -0.00562500  swing           A
# 5  0.004 -0.00765625  0.00078125  swing           A
# 6  0.005 -0.01000000  0.02234375  swing           A
# 7  0.006  0.01515625 -0.01296875  swing           A
# 8  0.007 -0.01375000 -0.07062500  swing           A
# 9  0.008  0.00968750  0.15343750  swing           A
# 10 0.009 -0.05203125  0.02984375  swing           A
# 11 0.010  0.12343750  0.00765625  swing           A
# 12 0.011 -0.05968750  0.00562500  swing           A
# 13 0.012 -0.09296875 -0.00187500  swing           A
# 14 0.013 -0.08343750 -0.11281250  swing           A
# 15 0.014 -0.00937500  0.00906250 stance           A
# 16 0.015 -0.00609375  0.02000000 stance           A
# 17 0.016  0.00890625  0.02093750 stance           A
# 18 0.017  0.02671875  0.00375000 stance           A
# 19 0.018 -0.00187500 -0.00031250 stance           A
# 20 0.019 -0.00171875  0.00171875 stance           A
```

If you really need `t_kinematics`, then just copy it over from `t_emg`:

```r
out$t_kinematics <- out$t_emg
```

---

We could also do a range-join:

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # fill
quux1 |>
  mutate(t_emg_next = lead(t_emg, default = Inf) - 1e-9) |>
  left_join(quux2, join_by(between(y$t_kinematics, x$t_emg, x$t_emg_next))) |>
  tidyr::fill(t_kinematics, Phase, stride_stop) |>
  select(-t_emg_next)
#    t_emg       CF_01       CF_02 t_kinematics  Phase stride_stop
# 1  0.000 -0.01796875  0.01234375        0.000  swing           A
# 2  0.001  0.00187500  0.05125000        0.000  swing           A
# 3  0.002  0.00828125 -0.04140625        0.002  swing           A
# 4  0.003 -0.01250000 -0.00562500        0.002  swing           A
# 5  0.004 -0.00765625  0.00078125        0.004  swing           A
# 6  0.005 -0.01000000  0.02234375        0.004  swing           A
# 7  0.006  0.01515625 -0.01296875        0.006  swing           A
# 8  0.007 -0.01375000 -0.07062500        0.006  swing           A
# 9  0.008  0.00968750  0.15343750        0.008  swing           A
# 10 0.009 -0.05203125  0.02984375        0.008  swing           A
# 11 0.010  0.12343750  0.00765625        0.010  swing           A
# 12 0.011 -0.05968750  0.00562500        0.010  swing           A
# 13 0.012 -0.09296875 -0.00187500        0.012  swing           A
# 14 0.013 -0.08343750 -0.11281250        0.012  swing           A
# 15 0.014 -0.00937500  0.00906250        0.014 stance           A
# 16 0.015 -0.00609375  0.02000000        0.014 stance           A
# 17 0.016  0.00890625  0.02093750        0.016 stance           A
# 18 0.017  0.02671875  0.00375000        0.016 stance           A
# 19 0.018 -0.00187500 -0.00031250        0.018 stance           A
# 20 0.019 -0.00171875  0.00171875        0.018 stance           A
```

The `1e-9` is to force the `between` comparison to be right-open; may not be required with your data, I wanted to be certain.

Comment: The first one seems to work well (I had not thought about assigning them to groups based upon the more fine-scale intervals). Question: do you know if `findInterval` works the same when the larger of the intervals is not perfectly divisible by the smaller? E.g., I have a few trials where the recordings are at 1000 hz and 475 hz; would `findInterval` still be useful? I understand that some of the categorical values would be binned at different resulting timesteps, but are there other issues with this?

Comment: There is no interpolation here. If a gap is 0.002 or 20, `findInterval` just returns which bin/gap is found. It requires monotonic and unique values, I believe.